# Azure Notification Hub Installation management via REST not making changes to hub

Tags: azure, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

I have been making use of Azure's REST API for the Notification Hub installation features.
Until recently, this has been working perfectly.

In the last few days, however, I have been having an issue of the changes I send not taking effect (ie. registrations not being created or deleted as needed), while still receiving success codes.

I tried creating an installation with legitimate data as well as fake data.
Example payload:

```
{
    "installationId": "eafa8bafbd17cef1",
    "userID": "073d9312-4aef-47bb-ac5d-45204e4dfe0f",
    "platform": "gcm",
    "pushChannel": "cjGjVrBWs4GWOZt1hS5Spg:APA91bE09LmsL3BtZN0u8mKyAJVdq_7AK5RjL_rKE7Y-o-8CDaOlCjY926iS_obUxUHyQCDYXCzJRnaTz0AB3qY_UUjW-6gFrmWzHQ6akdOpdiPF9zlsVk2_cS4Nsi9uUcR1BFTwGURT"
}
```

Doing so returns a 200 response, but if I do a get on that installationId it returns nothing. Additionally, getting the list of registrations doesn't show it either, which would work previously.

Same applies to delete. Success code (204), but doesn't remove the existing installation.

I tried to go through the legacy registration system, and this worked properly, but it doesn't fit my use case as well as the installation system.

I have tried recreating the notification hub, but it also suffered the same issue.

Comment: We are experiencing exactly the same issue. A week ago, everything worked fine, but now it's impossible to create new registrations or installations.

Comment: Sorry to hear you're experiencing this. It is not expected behavior. There is a known issue between November 14th, 2023 16:40 UTC and today (November 17th, 2023 18:45 UTC) that we have mitigated. It primarily impacted a subset of customers in the West Europe region. To confirm you were impacted, please file a support request through the Azure Portal.